# I am not migrate in python django

Tags: python, django, python-django-storages

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, main, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying main.0004_auto_20210301_2201...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: JSON_VALID

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute       
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv     
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration 
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 138, in alter_field 
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 571, in alter_field    
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 360, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 280, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(new_model)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute        
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\devia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute       
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: JSON_VALID
```

here is the traceback. plz someone help me with this no able to migrate.
first i create a progres json field in table and did not work so i drop it. now everything is not working plz help with his

Models.py is blank
and everything is blank but not able to migrate

here is the traceback. plz someone help me with this no able to migrate.
first i create a progres json field in table and did not work so i drop it. now everything is not working plz help with his

Models.py is blank
and everything is blank but not able to migrate

Comment: What database are you using? Can you share the database settings?

Comment: _"progres json"_ do you mean you used the JSONField from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`? That is meant for PostgreSQL only (deprecated in versions >=3.1). Since your `models.py` etc. is blank I would advice you to simply delete all migrations (keep the folder `migrations` and `__init__.py` inside it delete rest of files in the folder).